# Iterating Array in For Loop Returning Null

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, foreach

```html
<?php
//Called at start of page
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
 $dataset[] = $row;
}

//Called in middle of page, inside <table><tbody>
$dSize = count($dataset);
for( $i = 0; $i < $dSize; $i++){
//foreach($dataset as $row){
 $row = $dataset[$i];
 $thisIsId = true;
 echo "<tr>";
 $rSize = count($row);
 for( $j = 0; $j < $rSize; $j++){
 //foreach($row as $value){
  $value = $row[$j];
  //Next line output ex: <td id='r1c2' class='editable'>Bob
  echo "<td id='r$i" . "c$j'" . ($thisIsId ? "" : " class='editable'")  . ">$value";
  $thisIsId = false;
 }
}
?>
```

I'm trying to fill out a table that contains customer information, but $value keeps returning `null`. The `foreach` loops that are commented out are left there because these loops worked except I wasn't able to assign an id to the element based on `$i` and `$j` (obviously).

If I add a `console.log` of `json_encode($row)` after the line `$row = $dataset[$i];`, I get a JSON object that has all of the values filled out appropriately. As soon as I go into the nested for loop, I keep getting null values for `$value` AND `$row[$j]` if I just call that directly.

The ternary operator exists to check if it's the first column (the ID column) because that's the only cell that is not editable.

I've tried using `global $row` because I ran into a problem with scope in PHP before but it didn't seem to solve anything. I also tried renaming the `$row` variable to make sure it wasn't a conflict with when I use `$row` at the beginning of the page, but that also didn't solve anything.

**tl;dr** Why is `$value` returning `null` when used in a `for` loop but not when used in a `foreach` loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mysqli_fetch_assoc returns an associative array and not an ordered array : http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php.

So the key are the name of the column in your table that's why you cannot loop over it using a for loop. Use a foreach loop instead.

You should have a `E_NOTICE` error raised (Undefined index) in your nested loop.

Answer (score 0):

I have made necessary changes. I hope this gonna work. :)

Please provide `<table>` and `</table>` , above and bellow the php code respectively.

```
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $dataset[] = $row;
}
//Called in middle of page, inside <table><tbody>
$dSize = count($dataset);
$i = 1; 
foreach($dataset as $row){
       $thisIsId = true;
       echo "<tr>";
       $j = 1;
       foreach($row as $key=>$value){                   
            //Next line output ex: <td id='r1c2' class='editable'>Bob
            echo "<td id='r$i" . "c$j'" . ($thisIsId ? "" : " class='editable'")  . ">$value</td>";
            $thisIsId = false;
            $j++;
       }
       $i++;
       echo "</tr>";
}
?>
```